# How to parse the fields of StructType in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am writing a spark-jdbc program to read data from postgres db and move the same data to Hive on HDFS.
I am able to read the data from postgres. Before moving the data to Hive, I have to create the schema and table on Hive for the same data and with the datatypes given by our project which are similar to the ones on postgres.
For example:

```
source datatype                            Hive datatype
character varying\([0-9]{1,4}\)       ->    string
bigint                                ->    bigint
integer                               ->    int
smallint                              ->    int
numeric\([0-9]{1,3},0\)               ->    bigint
numeric\([0-9]{1,3},[1-9][0-9]{0,2}\) ->    double
```

If a column on source has the datatype `smallint`, it should be made `int` on Hive. I got the schema using the function 'schema'

```
val tbSchema = yearDF.schema
```

Now tbSchema is present in the form of :  `org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType` which I don't understand how to parse and read the values inside it.

For example, if StructType has: `StructType(StructField(id,IntegerType,false), StructField(name,StringType,true), StructField(company,StringType,true))`

How can I read it and extract the columnName and datatype from the collection so that I can use the same details to change the datatype and create schema for a hive table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`StructType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html) usually consists of sub-elements called [`StructField`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructField.html) which has a constructor like:

> ```
> StructField(String name, DataType dataType, boolean nullable, Metadata metadata)
> ```

To get these fields, you can just do

```
val tbSchema = yearDF.schema.map(s => (s.name, s.dataType))
```